# Using Request Method GET and params=formaction together in a single method

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, overriding, request-mapping

**I want to create a method which has both (@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) and @RequestMapping(params= "formaction= selectCustomer)) on the click of a SINGLE button**

This is because .GET method gets called first and that is a compulsory method whereas I want params="formaction= selectCustomer" to fetch customer details from the same method used in a different class.

I have already tried @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, params= "formaction= selectCustomer") but it did not work

```
@Resource (name = "control")
private Controller control;


@Override
@RequestScope
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, params= "formaction= selectCustomer")
public ModelAndView form(Request request, Model model, @ModelAttribute Command command, BindingResult result) {

return this.control.getData(request, model, command, result)
```

This getData method is in another class inside same package that usually gets all the data when accessed from a different workflow.

So basically I want the formAction to fetch me the customer data but how to use it with .GET ?

I also tried to make two seperate methods for .GET and formaction and I called the formaction method inside the .GET method but it did not fetch me the data. I am afraid I will get the data only if the method is called using param=formaction notation

Comment: Is it compiling?

Comment: Yes it is. But on clicking the button, it says webpage not found.

Comment: Wild guess but if you want both, couldn't you make two separate methods, with different RequestMappings, and one also calls the other?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't fetch me the details from the getData method.
It will fetch me the data if called as a formaction I suppose.

Comment: Not sure if it matters the order, but isn't method supposed to be after params?

Comment: That I am not sure of. Giving it a try..

Comment: No, even after having params as the first parameter and method as second, it still said webpage not available. The control is not even going in the class created if there are multiple parameters.

Comment: Is the webpage available when you don't do double mapping requests?